# Which HTTP response status code is most appropriate for a restricted URL?

Tags: 301-redirect, 404, 302-redirect, 403-forbidden, 401

I have a page on my website that's targeted at logged-in users only. Logged-out visitors shouldn't see the content.

Imagine the page URL is `example.com/upload/`.

In cases when users aren't authenticated (logged-out), would a 301, 302 or 404 response be most appropriate? Please explain why in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an error 401 = You are not authorised to view this page

However read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

A 301 redirect means that the page has permanently moved to a new location.

A 302 redirect means that the move is only temporary

A 404 redirect means that the page can't be found

Comment: 401, quote from wiki: `HTTP 401 is returned when the client has not authenticated, and implies that a successful response may be returned following valid authentication,`